# How to Loop Through Fields Checking if They're JSON Objects then Parsing Them Appropriately

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, parsing

I'm trying to solve a problem in which I want to dynamically be able to flatten tables in SQL server that may contain JSON objects within certain fields.

I need to be able to loop through each field, determine if it's in JSON format, then flatten them dynamically using the JSONValue() function in SQL Server.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxsjV.png

```
select SalesOrderNumber,
JSON_Value(JSONValue,'$.CustomerID') as CustomerID ,
JSON_Value(JSONValue,'$.OrderDate') as OrderDate ,
JSON_Value(JSONValue,'$.TotalDue') as TotalDue ,
JSON_Value(JSONValue,'$.ShipMethodID') as ShipMethodID ,
JSON_Value(JSONValue,'$.TerritoryID') as TerritoryID ,
JSON_Value(JSONValue,'$.SalesPersonID') as SalesPersonID 
from OrderHeaderJSON
```

The issue with this is that they would have to manually write out the function for each field and write the corresponding alias to it.

I'm not sure where to start --whether that be writing a stored procedure, function, utilizing cursors? I'm hoping somebody can point me to the right direction. I'm thinking to loop through each field, doing a ISJSON() to check if its json, then parsing it out correctly with an alias matching the key name in the JSON object.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to validate the data before it gets into the database, or on insert? I would go that route, if possible. Iterating through every row in the table each time you need to validate your JSON seems like an extreme amount of overhead.

Comment: Hi Jacob, these are prospective clients that contain this kind of data for some reason within their database. We pull their data into our business intelligence solution via a SQL query. I was just hoping for a more streamlined way to parse out their json objects within a field instead of having to be so verbose. I wasn't sure if there was some way to leverage T-SQL to automate this (I'm not very familiar with T-SQL).

Comment: If those are the requirements then so be it! Looking at your screenshot, I think you could possibly make it more streamlined by simply running ISJSON against the entire record, instead of by row. But I think using ISJSON is your best answer here.